# custom table cell displaying nil

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uibutton, custom-cell

I'm trying to set the title and display a button in my custom cell object in my second table view controller, but only my first dynamic prototype cell is displaying text.

The first prototype cell is UITableViewCell and the second is the custom object. In my first view controller I implement almost the same exact method and it works completely fine. Not sure where my error could be, the models I use have all their data in them. I have the correct cell identifier in my storyboard, and the connection from custom cell to the UIButton is set.

Thanks in advance.

Method:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CellIdentifier";
    static NSString *QuestionSectionIdentifier = @"QuestionSectionCell";

    if (indexPath.section == 0)
    {
        UITableViewCell *cellQuestion = [tableView
                                         dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:QuestionSectionIdentifier];
        if (cellQuestion == nil) {
            cellQuestion = [[UITableViewCell alloc]
                            initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle
                            reuseIdentifier:QuestionSectionIdentifier];
        }
        if (indexPath.row == 0) {
            cellQuestion.textLabel.text = _headerQuestion.question;
            NSLog(@"question here %@", cellQuestion.textLabel.text);
        }

        return cellQuestion;
    }
    else
    {
        MyTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[MyTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        }
        if (indexPath.section == 1)
        {
            if (indexPath.row == 0)
            {
                [cell.firstButton setTitle:_headerQuestion.questionAuthor.fullName forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                [cell.firstButton setTag:_headerQuestion.questionAuthor.userID];
                [cell.answerLabelField setHidden:YES];

                NSLog(@"section 1  %@", cell.firstButton.titleLabel.text);
            }
        }
        else  if (indexPath.section == 2)
        {
            Answer* answer_num =  [_headerQuestion.answers objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; //object at index
            [cell.firstButton setTitle:answer_num.answerAuthor.fullName forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [cell.firstButton setTag:answer_num.answerAuthor.userID];
            cell.answerLabelField.text = answer_num.answer;
        }
        return cell;
    }
}

-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 3;
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (section == 0)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    if (section == 1)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        return [_headerQuestion.answers count];
    }
}
```

Comment: What show "nil" exactly? `cell`? `cell.firstButton`?

Comment: I tried to log the text in cell.firstButton but it shows: (null). And only the cell for section 0, row 0  are displayed in my view controller, but none of the cells from MyTableViewCell are.

Comment: Are you sure `tableView(_:cellForRowAtIndexPath:) ` is getting called?

Comment: yes -- "section 1" from my Log is outputted

Comment: Would it be possible to view your project?

Comment: I can screen shot other locations, should I post MyTableViewCell files and the connections in Storyboard?

Comment: @khajj Can I see you `- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView` ?... which is your custom `cell`? :)

Comment: - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 3;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    if (section == 0) {
        return 1;
    }
    if (section == 1) {
        return 1;
    }
    else  {
        return [_headerQuestion.answers count];
    }
}

Comment: Please edit your original question with the additional code so it's easier to read.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you register both reuse identifiers with the tableview using

```
- (void)registerClass:(Class nullable)cellClass
  forCellReuseIdentifier:(NSString * nonnull)identifier
```

Or registerNib if you have a nib for the cell.

Comment: Oh, where do I call this? Also do you know why I was able to get the full display successfully on my first View Controller without using registerClass method?

Comment: @khajj a good place to register would be viewDidLoad or wherever you initialise your UITableView